# python-requests authenticated proxy httplib.BadStatusLine

Tags: python, curl, proxy, python-requests

Authenticated proxy through python-requests returns the following error:

```
>>> import requests
>>> proxies = {'https': 'http://username:password@proxy.company.com:8080',}
>>> requests.get('https://api.github.com/',proxies=proxies,verify=False)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 55, in get
    return request('get', url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 44, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 335, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 438, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 327, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='proxy.company.com', port=8080): Max retries exceeded with url: https://api.github.com/ (Caused by <class 'httplib.BadStatusLine'>: )
```

Authenticated proxy works fine in curl:

```
$ curl --proxy-user username:password --proxy http://proxy.company.com:8080 -k https://api.github.com/
{
  "current_user_url": "https://api.github.com/user",
  "authorizations_url": "https://api.github.com/authorizations",
  "emails_url": "https://api.github.com/user/emails",
  "emojis_url": "https://api.github.com/emojis",
  "events_url": "https://api.github.com/events",
  "feeds_url": "https://api.github.com/feeds",
  "following_url": "https://api.github.com/user/following{/target}",
  "gists_url": "https://api.github.com/gists{/gist_id}",
  "hub_url": "https://api.github.com/hub",
  "issue_search_url": "https://api.github.com/legacy/issues/search/{owner}/{repo}/{state}/{keyword}",
  "issues_url": "https://api.github.com/issues",
  "keys_url": "https://api.github.com/user/keys",
  "notifications_url": "https://api.github.com/notifications",
  "organization_repositories_url": "https://api.github.com/orgs/{org}/repos/{?type,page,per_page,sort}",
  "organization_url": "https://api.github.com/orgs/{org}",
  "public_gists_url": "https://api.github.com/gists/public",
  "rate_limit_url": "https://api.github.com/rate_limit",
  "repository_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/{owner}/{repo}",
  "repository_search_url": "https://api.github.com/legacy/repos/search/{keyword}{?language,start_page}",
  "current_user_repositories_url": "https://api.github.com/user/repos{?type,page,per_page,sort}",
  "starred_url": "https://api.github.com/user/starred{/owner}{/repo}",
  "starred_gists_url": "https://api.github.com/gists/starred",
  "team_url": "https://api.github.com/teams",
  "user_url": "https://api.github.com/users/{user}",
  "user_organizations_url": "https://api.github.com/user/orgs",
  "user_repositories_url": "https://api.github.com/users/{user}/repos{?type,page,per_page,sort}",
  "user_search_url": "https://api.github.com/legacy/user/search/{keyword}"
}
```

How do I troubleshoot?

Comment: This should be fixed with Requests 2.0: https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/pull/1515

Comment: If you make this an answer I will mark this resolved. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Requests has support for HTTP proxies just since 2.0: https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/pull/1515

BTW, it does respect proxy environment variables, so you can just set:

```
export http_proxy="http://username:password@proxy.company.com:8080"
export https_proxy=$http_proxy
```

More details about the state of proxy support in requests 1.x can be found in this blog post: https://lukasa.co.uk/2013/07/Python_Requests_And_Proxies/

Answer (score 0):

Your proxy is indeed HTTP not HTTPS. To use proxy with HTTPS it needs to use connect protocol, not HTTP, with presumably CONNECT basic auth. Now I do not have a HTTPS proxy with auth available, and do not know how to install such system, but what happens if you have just `"https://username:password@proxy.company.com:8080"` there instead?

On the other hand, you might want to make sure that requests/urllib3 are up to date. [See this bug report](https://github.com/shazow/urllib3/issues/50).

Comment: Antti, thanks for your response. We use HTTPS via HTTP proxy. Hence, changing proxies to a target host of HTTPS would not solve the issue. I have updated the curl example in the question to clarify the HTTP proxy.